# How to detect simple shapes (using emgu cv), when a contour can be torn?

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, emgucv, contour

I need to find the coordinates of the most popular simple shapes (usually - rectangles) in the picture. I used the approach that has been described here ([Simple approach for finding rectangles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35251367/5341912) ). But I've faced with the situation shown in the picture. Some boxes have a torn border and I cannot detect them with standard approach. These rectangles circled in red.
[image: Objects have torn contours] What solution would you suggest?

UPDATE:

Using dilation/erosion before binarization:

1. Dilation

[image: Dilate image before binarization]

2. Erosion

[image: Erode image before binarization]

Comment: Please post the original image without the red circles.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a simple dilation using a small structuring element
2. Find connected component
3. For each connected component i would calculate the ratio between the number of pixels in the component divided by the area of the bounding box i would keep only the ones that are very close to 1.

Comment: thank you for your comment, it seems, that you algorithm should work, but when I do first step (dilation or erosion), some boundaries disappear, and related objects merge. I added Illustrations to these cases to the description.