# Extract rectangle, drop it and rotate image in opencv

Tags: opencv, rotation, bounding-box

I have an issue want to ask you guys.
Now i want to make the rectangle (like as the red line in image) base on four points (black square in image) and then drop it become new image to keep process.

After that I want to rotate this image balance (90 degree). But I don't know how to do that?

Anyone can help me please?
Thanks!

This is my image:
[image]

Comment: You could rotate it around its center by a single degree/radians until your black squares align pairwise on the same x-coordinate.

Comment: But there are only 3 points(black squares) in the image

Comment: @TA I known that but i dont know how to get black squares point. The value of top left black squares is minimum y-coordinate. Can you give me some ideas to get point of black squares?

Comment: @ZdaR yup, because this image is not balance when i scan the paper

Comment: @user1465351 you can erode to get rid of all thin lines, and then use findContours to get your black squares.then just take the central coordinate of each square.

Comment: @ZdaR 2 squares are already sufficient to correctly align the image

Comment: you can start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35251367/5008845)

Comment: @Miki oh yeah, that is correct answer. its helpful thanks