# Matching pdf pages against pattern using python and openCV

Tags: computer-vision, opencv, python

I have a pdf with lots of pages, and I want to find what pages match a certain pattern. These pages are used as separators between different sections of the document.
Basically, I want to find the pages that have the 4 little black squares in the corners (see examples at the end of the question). I am sure that the separators are the only pages with those black squares.
I'm trying to use python and opencv to obtain this result, but I don't think I understand it well enough. I also tried using a mask but still no result.

Here is the code I wrote (sorry if it's kind of a mess, I stitched it up from tutorials and other SO answers):

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import fitz

filename = 'test.pdf'
template = cv2.imread('template.png', 0)
w, h = template.shape[::-1]
mask = cv2.imread('mask_edit.png', 0)
page_matches = list()

pdf_doc = fitz.open(filename)
for index, page in enumerate(pdf_doc.pages()):
    pix = page.get_pixmap(alpha=0)
    im = np.frombuffer(pix.samples, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(pix.h, pix.w, pix.n)
    img_bgr = np.ascontiguousarray(im[..., [2, 1, 0]], dtype=np.uint8) # rgb to bgr
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img_bgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    method = cv2.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED
    res = cv2.matchTemplate(img, template, method, mask)
    min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)
    found = (max_val, max_loc)
    treshold = 0.5
    if (max_val >= treshold):
        print(index, found)
```

I also tried using different cv2 methods:

- when I use cv2.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED or cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED I get 0 matches in the whole file
- when I use cv2.TM_CCORR_NORMED all pages match with a score higher than 0.99

Thanks in advance!

Here are the images:

The template I'm using
[image: This is the template]

A page that matches the template
[image: this is a page that matches the template]

A page that does not match the template
[image: this is a page that does not match].

The mask I tried to use (white squares are a little bigger than the black squares I'm trying to match)
[image: the mask]

Comment: template matching isn't going to work. It's better (and easier) to check if those rectangle are in the image... something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/35251367/5008845

Comment: @Miki thank you so much! I agree that solution is better and works flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question for future reference, it's way better to adapt [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35251367/4271408) to my use case.
Here is the python code:

```py
import cv2
import fitz
import numpy as np

filename = 'test.pdf'
pdf_doc = fitz.open(filename)
page_matches = set()

for index, page in enumerate(pdf_doc.pages()):
    pix = page.get_pixmap(alpha=0)
    im = np.frombuffer(pix.samples, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(pix.h, pix.w, pix.n)
    img = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    _, binary_img = cv2.threshold(img, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    inverted_binary_img = cv2.bitwise_not(binary_img)
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(inverted_binary_img, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    for contour in contours:
        box = cv2.minAreaRect(contour)
        (x, y), (box_width, box_height), angle = box
        c_area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
        b_area = box_width * box_height
        if (
            b_area > 0 and
            c_area > 0 and
            c_area / b_area > 0.95 and
            min(box_width, box_height) / max(box_width, box_height) > 0.95 and
            15.0 < box_width < 20.0
        ):
            page_matches.add(index + 1)

for i in page_matches:
    print("Page found!", i)
```